# link to Express react WITHOUT creating-react-app

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I only know the react and node JS express bundle, so I need help. Perhaps this question has already been asked by someone, but I personally did not find the same question with the same stack.
The question is as follows:

How to link queries in express to MySQL data transfer in react component
I made some initial settings for webpack, babel and now the component is given to the request/, but I know that you need to link react and express via a proxy, since this technology is used in create-react-app.

This is the tree structure of my app now:

[image]

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

.babellrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

express.js:

```
const path = require('path'),
      express = require('express'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
      app = express(),
      mysql = require('mysql2');

const conn = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'internet_magazine',
    password: 'Plmoknn1605',
    port: '3306'
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    conn.query('select * from table', (err,result) => {
       // how to pass data to react component and return it with this data 
    });
});
```

PS. most likely, I did something incorrectly, but I can't figure it out myself, so I will be happy to get any help

Comment: Sorry, you are trying to make a call to the MySQL directly from a react app?

Comment: no, I need to pass data from mysql to react component and send a ready-made page with this data to the client

Comment: your need `res.json(result)`

Comment: but I need to pass this data to the react component

Answer (score 0):

I would personally split the project into two:
First app which is just plain react and will make the call to necessary apis from it when needed. Uses js fetch/axios/something else where needed to make the call.
Second app whose sole responsibility is to be connected to a MySQL DB and expose necessary apis which the first app can call and use.

Justification(to name a few):
You want the two apps to run independently and as reusable as possible.
If one app is down, other app should not be affected.
Different teams can work on different apps instead all working on the same app.

Comment: since these two applications will work on different ports (for example, 3000 and 3500), how do I get them to communicate(I assume through a proxy, but I haven't worked with it before)?

Comment: From the react app which is running on say port 3000, try to call the second app which is running on 3500 using Axios/js fetch

Comment: so I will have to write something like this "fetch('localhost:3500/getData')"in every request?

Comment: Yes, every time you load the page, do that. And once that request is complete, return the whole page.